# Blazor WASM CheckSession Loop

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, openid-connect, webassembly

We have a new Blazor WASM app that authenticates against IdentityServer4 using the default template that Microsoft provide and it all works fine except I am not sure if the CheckSession iframe is working correctly as it keep running in an infinite loop.

So from my understanding the Authentication library generates a CheckSession IFrame that then creates another iframe to check the session against IdentityServer but this continually does this about every second (maybe even less) and my understanding is that it is supposed to do this? However I would have thought there would be a way to set the interval in how often it checks but I can't seem to find one.

iframe generated:

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:5000/connect/checksession" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; display: none; width: 0px; height: 0px;"></iframe>
```

Which intern generates another iframe every second:

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:5000/connect/authorize?..." style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; display: none; width: 0px; height: 0px;"></iframe>
```

It appears that other SPA apps have the ability to set a checkSessionInterval property but I can't find one for Blazor?

So my questions are:

1. Is the checkSession IFrame supposed to check so often (less than every second)
2. Is there a way to set the interval?
3. Is there even a way to turn this off and do it manually?

Comment: Did you find a solution for the loop? I'm seeing the same 1 second checksession iframe loop as well with blazor wasm.

Comment: @gilm0079 no we didn't find any answer to this and have really just accepted it as it is doing what it supposed to and there is no way to change the configuration.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I ran into something similar in another project using angular. It used the oidc-client-js library. I think I was able to set an interval in that library on the check session to slow it down. I'll keep looking to see if the same can be done for the blazor wasm auth library.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I was able to get my WASM project stable. Not sure if this will help you, but I think the main issues I was having was how blazor was bootstrapping. It might have been trying to run two instances of blazor wasm on the page. This may have caused the auth to battle each other and create the loop.

I did have a component element decorated with the render-mode attribute on the page to bootstrap blazor, but it seems like it works better to just let the program.cs bootstrap blazor by declaring the App root component pointing to a div on the page to pin the blazor app to.

```
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
```